# PyCharm: ImportError: No module named 'websocket'

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

i recently reinstalled pycharm, and imported an old project that uses websockets.
I have a python interpreter (2.7) set and added the websocket module to it. Theres a folder called "websocket" in C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages, and that path is in the list of path the interpreter uses.

There are no errors shown in the code, but when i run it i get
"ImportError: No module named 'websocket'"

[image]

Comment: How are you running your project? Are you using `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and it took a while for me to realize the interpreter is simply communicating with Pycharm -- it is not necessarily telling Pycharm which environment to run.

Look in 'Edit Configurations...' (a drop down at the top of Pycharm near the right).  If you setup a script in there then ensure it has the same Python Interpreter as your settings. Usually the interpreter in your settings is at the top of this list and is tagged as 'Default'.