# PyCharm - code runs in PyCharm terminal, but not for “Run” button

Tags: python, pandas, terminal, pycharm

When I run the code in the PyCharm terminal with "python filename.py", everything works (I am using a venv). But when I click the run button at the top (or when I right click the file name and click run), I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/file/fileName.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I have pandas installed. I notice for clicking "Run", the directory says

```
C:/Users/file/fileName.py
```

but for "python filename.py" the directory says

```
(venv) C:\Users\file
```

Is there something that I can do to fix this?

Comment: Be sure you are using the same virtual environment in PyCharm as you are on the terminal.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the PyCharm terminal.  Is there something I have to do to make sure it's using the venv in this terminal? I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: I answered a similar question a while back -- make sure your configuration in PyCharm is set correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622461/pycharm-importerror-no-module-named-websocket/36343945#36343945

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can run your code in the PyCharm terminal without a problem, correct? In order to run by clicking the Run button, you need to set the virtual environment in your PyCharm project.

Comment: Here's a link to show you how to do it ^